# Что такое метаклассы в Python?

Tags: python, ооп

Что такое метаклассы в Python и для чего нужно их использовать?

<sub>перевод вопроса [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/14227417) участника [@e-satis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9951/e-satis)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/14227417

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Классы как объекты

Прежде чем разбираться в метаклассах, нужно пройти мастер-классы по Python. Python имеет очень своеобразное представление о том, что такое классы, заимствованное из языка Smalltalk.

В большинстве языков класс - это просто фрагменты кода, которые описывают, как создать объект. Это отчасти верно и в Python:

```
>>> class ObjectCreator(object):
...       pass
...

>>> my_object = ObjectCreator()
>>> print(my_object)
<__main__.ObjectCreator object at 0x8974f2c>
```

Но в Python классы это нечто большее. Классы это тоже объекты.

Да, объекты.

Как только вы используете ключевое слово `class`, Python выполняет его и создает объект. Данные  создаст в памяти объект с именем «ObjectCreator».

```
>>> class ObjectCreator(object):
...       pass
...
```

Этот объект (класс) сам по себе может создавать объекты (экземпляры), и поэтому он является классом.

Но все же это объект, а значит

- Вы можете присвоить его переменной
- Вы можете скопировать его
- Вы можете добавить к нему атрибуты
- Вы можете передать его как параметр функции

например:

```
>>> print(ObjectCreator) # Вы можете распечатать класс, потому что это объект
<class '__main__.ObjectCreator'>
>>> def echo(o):
...       print(o)
...
>>> echo(ObjectCreator) # Вы можете передать класс в качестве параметра
<class '__main__.ObjectCreator'>
>>> print(hasattr(ObjectCreator, 'new_attribute'))
False
>>> ObjectCreator.new_attribute = 'foo' # Вы можете добавлять атрибуты в класс
>>> print(hasattr(ObjectCreator, 'new_attribute'))
True
>>> print(ObjectCreator.new_attribute)
foo
>>> ObjectCreatorMirror = ObjectCreator # Вы можете назначить класс переменной
>>> print(ObjectCreatorMirror.new_attribute)
foo
```

## Динамическое создание классов

Поскольку классы являются объектами, вы можете создавать их на лету, как и любой объект.

Во-первых, вы можете создать класс в функции, используя `class`

```
>>> def choose_class(name):
...     if name == 'foo':
...         class Foo(object):
...             pass
...         return Foo # вернуть класс, а не экземпляр
...     else:
...         class Bar(object):
...             pass
...         return Bar
...
>>> MyClass = choose_class('foo')
>>> print(MyClass) # функция возвращает класс, а не экземпляр
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> print(MyClass()) # вы можете из этого создать объект
<__main__.Foo object at 0x89c6d4c>
```

Но это не так динамично, так как вам все равно придется писать весь класс самостоятельно.

Поскольку классы являются объектами, они должны быть созданы чем-то.

Когда вы используете ключевое слово `class`, Python создает этот объект автоматически. Но, как и в большинстве случаев в Python, он позволяет делать это вручную.

Помните функцию `type`? Старая добрая функция, которая позволяет узнать, к какому типу относится объект:

```
>>> print(type(1))
<type 'int'>

>>> print(type("1"))
<type 'str'>

>>> print(type(ObjectCreator))
<type 'type'>

>>> print(type(ObjectCreator()))
<class '__main__.ObjectCreator'>
```

Что ж, у `type` есть совершенно другие возможности, он также может создавать классы на лету. `type` может принимать описание класса как параметры и возвращать класс

(Я знаю, глупо, что одна и та же функция может иметь два совершенно разных использования в зависимости от параметров, которые вы ей передаете. Это проблема из-за обратной совместимости в Python)

`type` работает следующим образом:

```
type(name, bases, attrs)
```

Где:

- `name`: название класса
- `base`: кортеж родительских классов для наследования (может быть пустым)
- `attrs`: словарь, содержащий имена и значения атрибутов

пример:

```
>>> class MyShinyClass(object):
...       pass
```

можно создать вручную следующим образом:

```
>>> MyShinyClass = type('MyShinyClass', (), {}) # returns a class object
>>> print(MyShinyClass)
<class '__main__.MyShinyClass'>
>>> print(MyShinyClass()) # создать экземпляр из класса
<__main__.MyShinyClass object at 0x8997cec>
```

Вы заметите, что мы используем «MyShinyClass» как имя класса и как переменную для хранения ссылки на класс. Они могут быть разными, но нет причин усложнять ситуацию.

`type` принимает словарь для определения атрибутов класса

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...       bar = True
```

Можно превратить в:

```
>>> Foo = type('Foo', (), {'bar':True})
```

И использовать как обычный класс:

```
>>> print(Foo)
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> print(Foo.bar)
True
>>> f = Foo()
>>> print(f)
<__main__.Foo object at 0x8a9b84c>
>>> print(f.bar)
True
```

И, конечно, вы можете наследовать от него:

```
>>>   class FooChild(Foo):
...         pass
```

либо

```
>>> FooChild = type('FooChild', (Foo,), {})
>>> print(FooChild)
<class '__main__.FooChild'>
>>> print(FooChild.bar) # bar унаследован от Foo
True
```

В конце концов, вы захотите добавить методы в свой класс. Просто определите функцию с соответствующей сигнатурой и назначьте ее как атрибут.

```
>>> def echo_bar(self):
...       print(self.bar)
...
>>> FooChild = type('FooChild', (Foo,), {'echo_bar': echo_bar})
>>> hasattr(Foo, 'echo_bar')
False
>>> hasattr(FooChild, 'echo_bar')
True
>>> my_foo = FooChild()
>>> my_foo.echo_bar()
True
```

После динамического создания класса вы можете добавить еще больше методов, точно так же, как добавление методов к нормально созданному объекту класса

```
>>> def echo_bar_more(self):
...       print('yet another method')
...
>>> FooChild.echo_bar_more = echo_bar_more
>>> hasattr(FooChild, 'echo_bar_more')
True
```

Вы видите, к чему мы идем: в Python классы - это объекты, и вы можете создавать классы на лету, динамически.

Это то, что делает Python, когда вы используете ключевое слово `class`, и он это делает с помощью метаклассов

## Что такое метаклассы

Метаклассы - это «материал», который создает классы.

Вы определяете классы для создания объектов, верно?

Но мы узнали, что классы Python - это объекты.

Что ж, метаклассы создают эти объекты. Это классы классов, вы можете изобразить их так:

```
MyClass = MetaClass()
my_object = MyClass()
```

Вы видели, что `type` позволяет делать что-то вроде этого:

```
MyClass = type('MyClass', (), {})
```

Это потому, что функция `type` на самом деле является метаклассом. `type` - это метакласс, который Python использует для создания всех классов за кулисами.

Теперь вы задаетесь вопросом, какого черта это написано строчными буквами, а не `Type`?

Что ж, я думаю, это вопрос согласованности с `str`, классом, который создает строковые объекты, и `int` с классом, который создает целочисленные объекты. `type` - это просто класс, который создает объекты класса.

Вы увидите это, проверив атрибут `__class__`.

Все, абсолютно все, в Python является объектом. Сюда входят целые числа, строки, функции и классы. Все они объекты. И все они созданы из класса:

```
>>> age = 35
>>> age.__class__
<type 'int'>

>>> name = 'bob'
>>> name.__class__
<type 'str'>

>>> def foo(): pass
>>> foo.__class__
<type 'function'>

>>> class Bar(object): pass
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.__class__
<class '__main__.Bar'>
```

Теперь, что такое `__class__` у любого `__class__`?

```
>>> age.__class__.__class__
<type 'type'>
>>> name.__class__.__class__
<type 'type'>
>>> foo.__class__.__class__
<type 'type'>
>>> b.__class__.__class__
<type 'type'>
```

Итак, метакласс - это просто материал, который создает объекты класса.

Если хотите, можете назвать это «фабрикой классов».

`type` - это встроенный метакласс, который использует Python, но, конечно, вы можете создать свой собственный метакласс.

## Атрибут **metaclass**

#### Метаклассы в Python 2

В Python 2 вы можете добавить атрибут `__metaclass__` при написании класса (синтаксис Python 3 см. В следующем разделе):

```
class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = something... # Что-нибудь
    [...]
```

Если вы это сделаете, Python будет использовать метакласс для создания класса `Foo`.

Осторожно, это сложно.

Сначала вы пишете `class Foo(object)`, но объект класса `Foo` еще не создан в памяти.

Python будет искать `__metaclass__` в определении класса. Если он его найдет, он будет использовать его для создания класса объекта `Foo`. Если это не так, он будет использовать `type` для создания класса.

Прочтите это несколько раз

Когда вы сделаете это:

```
class Foo(Bar):
    pass
```

Python делает следующее:

Есть ли в `Foo` атрибут `__metaclass__`?

Если да, создайте в памяти объект класса с именем `Foo`, используя то, что находится в `__metaclass__`.

Если Python не может найти `__metaclass__`, он будет искать `__metaclass__` на уровне MODULE и пытаться сделать то же самое (но только для классов, которые ничего не наследуют, в основном классов старого стиля).

Затем, если он вообще не может найти какой-либо `__metaclass__`, он будет использовать собственный метакласс `Bar` (первого родителя который может быть по умолчанию `type`) для создания объекта класса.

Будьте осторожны: атрибут `__metaclass__` не будет унаследован, а метакласс родительского элемента (`Bar.__class__`) будет. Если `Bar` использовал атрибут `__metaclass__`, который создал `Bar` с `type()` (а не `type.__new__()`), подклассы не унаследуют это поведение

Теперь главный вопрос: что можно добавить в `__metaclass__`?

Ответ - то, что может создать класс.

А что может создать класс? `type` или что-либо, что его подклассы используют

#### Метаклассы в Python 3

Синтаксис для установки метакласса был изменен в Python 3:

```
class Foo(object, metaclass=something):
    ...
```

Т.е. атрибут `__metaclass__` больше не используется, а был превращен в аргумент в списке родительских классов

Однако [поведение метаклассов](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) в основном остается неизменным.

Одна вещь, добавленная к метаклассам в Python 3, заключается в том, что вы также можете передавать атрибуты как ключевые слова-аргументы в метакласс, например:

```
class Foo(object, metaclass=something, kwarg1=value1, kwarg2=value2):
    ...
```

Прочтите раздел ниже, чтобы узнать, как Python справляется с этим.

## Пользовательские метаклассы

Основная цель метакласса, автоматически изменять класс при его создании.

Обычно вы делаете это для API, где хотите создавать классы, соответствующие текущему контексту.

Представьте себе глупый пример, в котором вы решили, что атрибуты всех классов в вашем модуле должны быть написаны в верхнем регистре. Есть несколько способов сделать это, но один из них - установить `__metaclass__` на уровне модуля.

Таким образом, все классы этого модуля будут созданы с использованием этого метакласса, и нам просто нужно указать метаклассу перевести все атрибуты в верхний регистр.

К счастью, `__metaclass__` на самом деле может быть любым вызываемым объектом, он не обязательно должен быть формальным классом (я знаю, что что-то с «class» в его имени не обязательно должно быть классом, поймите… это полезно).

Итак, мы начнем с простого примера, используя функцию.

```
# метаклассу автоматически передаются те же аргументы
# которые вы обычно передаете в `type`
def upper_attr(future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attrs):
    """
       Вернётся объект класса со списком его атрибутов
       в верхнем регистре.
    """
    # выберим все атрибуты, которые не начинается с '__'
    # и поставим их в верхний регистр
    uppercase_attrs = {
        attr if attr.startswith("__") else attr.upper(): v
        for attr, v in future_class_attrs.items()
    }

    # пусть `type` создаст класс
    return type(future_class_name, future_class_parents, uppercase_attrs)

__metaclass__ = upper_attr # это повлияет на все классы в модуле

class Foo(): # __metaclass__ не будет работать с «объектом»
    # но мы можем определить здесь __metaclass__, чтобы воздействовать только на этот класс
    # и это будет работать с дочерними элементами «объекта» 
    bar = 'bip'
```

Давайте проверим:

```
>>> hasattr(Foo, 'bar')
False
>>> hasattr(Foo, 'BAR')
True
>>> Foo.BAR
'bip'
```

Теперь сделаем то же самое, но с использованием реального класса для метакласса:

```
# помните, что `type` на самом деле является классом вроде `str` и `int`
# так что вы можете унаследовать от него
class UpperAttrMetaclass(type):
    # __new__ - это метод, вызываемый до __init__
    # это метод, который создает объект и возвращает его
    # в то время как __init__ просто инициализирует объект, переданный как параметр
    # вы редко используете __new__, за исключением случаев
    # когда вы хотите контролировать, как объект создаётся 
    # здесь созданный объект - это класс, и мы хотим его настроить
    # поэтому мы переопределяем __new__
    # вы можете делать кое-что и в __init__, если хотите
    # при продвинутом использовании нужно также переопределить __call__, но мы не будем делать это
    def __new__(upperattr_metaclass, future_class_name,
                future_class_parents, future_class_attrs):
        uppercase_attrs = {
            attr if attr.startswith("__") else attr.upper(): v
            for attr, v in future_class_attrs.items()
        }
        return type(future_class_name, future_class_parents, uppercase_attrs)
```

Давайте перепишем приведенное выше, но с более короткими и более реалистичными именами переменных, теперь, когда мы знаем, что они означают:

```
class UpperAttrMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
        uppercase_attrs = {
            attr if attr.startswith("__") else attr.upper(): v
            for attr, v in attrs.items()
        }
        return type(clsname, bases, uppercase_attrs)
```

Возможно, вы заметили дополнительный аргумент `cls`. В этом нет ничего особенного: `__new__` всегда получает класс, в котором он определен, в качестве первого параметра. Точно так же, как у вас есть `self` для обычных методов, которые получают экземпляр в качестве первого параметра, или определяющий класс для методов класса.

Но это неправильное ООП. Мы вызываем `type` напрямую и не переопределяем и не вызываем родительский `__new__`.

```
class UpperAttrMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
        uppercase_attrs = {
            attr if attr.startswith("__") else attr.upper(): v
            for attr, v in attrs.items()
        }
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, uppercase_attrs)
```

Мы можем сделать его еще чище, используя `super`, который упростит наследование (потому что, у вас могут быть метаклассы которые наследуются от метаклассов):

```
class UpperAttrMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
        uppercase_attrs = {
            attr if attr.startswith("__") else attr.upper(): v
            for attr, v in attrs.items()
        }
        return super(UpperAttrMetaclass, cls).__new__(
            cls, clsname, bases, uppercase_attrs)
```

Вот и все. Больше в метаклассах больше ничего нет.

Причина сложности кода с использованием метаклассов заключается не в метаклассах, а в том, что вы обычно используете метаклассы для выполнения извращенных вещей, основанных на интроспекции, манипулировании наследованием, переменными, такими как `__dict__` и т.д.

В самом деле, метаклассы особенно полезны для черной магии и, следовательно, для сложных вещей. Но сами по себе они просты:

- Перехватить создание класса
- Изменить класс
- Вернуть измененный класс

## Зачем для метаклассов использовать классы, а не функций?

Поскольку **metaclass** может принимать любые вызываемые объекты, зачем использовать класс, если он явно более сложен?

Для этого есть несколько причин:

- Ясные намерение. Когда вы читаете `UpperAttrMetaclass(type)`, вы знаете, что будет дальше
- Вы можете использовать ООП. Метакласс может наследоватся от метакласса, переопределять родительские методы. Метаклассы могут даже использовать метаклассы.
- Подклассы класса будут экземплярами его метакласса, если вы укажите метакласс с помощью класса, а не с помощью функции.
- Вы можете лучше структурировать свой код. Вы никогда не используете метаклассы для чего-то столь же тривиального, как приведенный выше пример. Обычно это для чего-то сложного. Возможность создавать несколько методов и группировать их в один класс очень полезно для облегчения чтения кода.
- Вы можете подключиться к `__new__`, `__init__` и `__call__`. Это позволит вам делать разные вещи. Даже если обычно вы можете делать все это в `__new__`, некоторым людям просто удобнее использовать `__init__`.
- Они называются метаклассами, черт возьми! Это должно что-то значить!

## Зачем использовать метаклассы?

А теперь большой вопрос. Зачем использовать какую-то непонятную функцию, подверженную ошибкам?

Ну, обычно вы этого не делаете:

> Метаклассы - это более глубокая магия, и 99% пользователей не должны беспокоиться об этом. Если вы задаетесь вопросом, нужны ли они вам, то нет (люди, которым они действительно нужны, чтобы точно знать, что они им нужны, и не нуждаются в объяснении почему).

Python гуру Tim Peters.

Основной вариант использования метакласса - создание API. Типичным примером этого является Django ORM. Это позволяет вам определить что-то вроде этого:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

Но если вы сделаете это:

```
person = Person(name='bob', age='35')
print(person.age)
```

Он не вернет объект `IntegerField`. Он вернет `int` и даже может взять его прямо из базы данных.

Это возможно, потому что `models.Model` определяет `__metaclass__` и использует некоторую магию, которая превратит `Person`, которую вы только что определили с помощью простых операторов, в сложный крючок для поля базы данных.

Django делает что-то сложное простым, предоставляя простой API и используя метаклассы, воссоздавая код из этого API, чтобы делать реальную работу за кулисами.

## Последнее слово

Во-первых, вы знаете, что классы - это объекты, которые могут создавать экземпляры.

На самом деле классы сами по себе являются экземплярами метаклассов.

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
>>> id(Foo)
142630324
```

В Python все является объектом, и все они являются экземплярами классов или экземплярами метаклассов.

Кроме `type`

`type` на самом деле является отдельным метаклассом. Это не то, что вы могли бы воспроизвести на чистом Python, это делается путем небольшого мошенничества на уровне реализации.

Во-вторых, метаклассы сложны. Возможно, вы не захотите использовать их для очень простых изменений класса. Вы можете менять классы, используя два разных методы:

- [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)
- Декораторы классов

В 99% случаев, когда вам нужно изменить класс, вам лучше использовать их.

Но в 98% случаев вам вообще не нужно менять класс.

<sub>перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/14227417) от участника [@e-satis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9951/e-satis)</sub>